# Installing a config file for a new service added to systemd/system dir

Tags: software-installation, systemd

Installing [informix](https://www.cursor-distribution.de/aktuell.12.10.xC1/documentation/ids_ix_bookmap.pdf) config file for service described in systemd/system - config needs to go under /etc/sysconfig - but there is no such directory. Should I create the directory, if so as root and with what permissions?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, the best way is to call IBM, in my general sense 'yes, and 644'.

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/sysconfig` is coming from the Red Hat world, in debian/ubuntu world `/etc/default` is usually used.

Now the question is, does the systemd .service file explicitly reference `/etc/sysconfig`? if so I would just create the directory (with mode 0755) and put the file there to avoid modifying the service IBM is shipping and call it a day.

If you really want to follow the debian/ubuntu "standards" you could also have a look at [systemd drop-ins](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) to override the directive without modifying the complete file.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful direction.  I've been away for a while and systemd is totally new and strange. Hit this also when trying to install a desktop on an Arch Linux pi system. The old inid.d system was much simpler. systemctl enable XXXX.service creates a link from /etc/systemd/system/filename -> /usr/lib/systemd/system/realname.service. I will give this a try and read up on the new and supposedly better (?) init.d system.

Answer (score 0):

My problem installing a service file on Ubuntu/Linux 19.10 which uses both the SysV BSD startup utility and the new systemd startup system - so 2 problems: 1. my SysV startup script (with its dependencies) and 2. my systemd service file, also with some errors, which systemd reported as problems with the LSB file (my faulty script). The systemd seems to work with the SysV scripts. Problem solved: removed my SvsV script and its kill and start dirs, fixed up my systemd script, and in brief, did a systemctl start realnamex.service.

Thanks for pointing my in the right direction. Systemd is a new and better way. Good info can be found at the following:

General: 
https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/understanding-and-using-systemd

Systemd syscntl util: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sysctmctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units

Good blog info on systemd:
http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd-for-admins-3.html

Peace